# How can I prevent a key press event on an input field from bubbling up to the form?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have a form and one of the fields allows users to add tags. I want to build it so it's possible to add the tags with a click on enter. Problem is, whenever enter is clicked the tag is added but also the form thinks it's being submitted. How can I prevent it, so the form only get's submitted when the submit button is clicked?

This is my form:

```
<form>

            <div className="tiny-margin-bottom medium-margin-top">
              <InputField
                type="text"
                placeHolder="Add tags that are related to your business (for example 'Restaurant')"
                value={tagInput}
                onChange={setTagInput}
                onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
                label="Hit 'Enter' to save tags"
              />
              <div className="tags">
                {values && values.tags ? renderTags(values.tags) : null}
              </div>
            </div>

            {formError ? (
              <div className="form-error small-margin-top">
                Please fill out all three fields
              </div>
            ) : null}
            <div className="popup__button medium-margin-top">
              <button className="boxed-button " onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Launch
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

And these are the two methods I am trying to work with-

This one is for when enter is clicked (should nly serve the input field):

```
  const handleKeyPress = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      if (!(values && values.tags)) values.tags = [];
      if (values.tags.includes(tagInput) || !tagInput.length) return;
      setValues({ tags: [...values.tags, tagInput.toLowerCase()] });
      setTagInput("");
    }
  };
```

And this one is for submition:

```
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!!values.title && values.country && values.lang) {
      setSubmitting(true);
      newProject(values, setSubmitting);
    } else {
      setFormError(true);
    }
  };
```

I've also tried this as the action for onKeyPress:

```
onKeyPress={e => {
handleKeyPress(e) && e.preventDefault();
}}
```

But it dodn't work.

EDIT:

By Jay's suggestion (if I used it correctly), I've tried the following and it still doesn't fix it:

```
  const handleKeyPress = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      if (!(values && values.tags)) values.tags = [];
      if (values.tags.includes(tagInput) || !tagInput.length) return;
      setValues({ tags: [...values.tags, tagInput.toLowerCase()] });
      setTagInput("");
    }
    return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop the event to bubble up:

```
const handleKeyPress = event => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // <-----add this line
```

or you can `return false;` from the handler as it can do two things for you:

- `event.preventDefault()`
- `event.stopPropagation()`

You can add it after this line:

```
setTagInput("");
return false; //<-------here it will work only if enter is pressed
```

Comment: Still can't make it work. I've tried both even at the same time. Added it to my question for you to see